# Multithread Pytest

Tags: pytest, pytest-xdist

I wanted to create a test in PyTest where it will parallelly open two Chrome and Firefox browser and test two test cases one by one with valid and invalid sets of inputs. How should I achieve it?

Thanks for your advanced help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using following methods

1. Selenium Grid and docker.
   Download docker and pull the image for Selenium Hub and Image for Chrome and Image for Firefox. Start the containers and you are good to go.
   You can follow the instruction from this page.

- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

2. If you do not want to use docker then, you can download selenium grid jar file for hub and nodes in your local machine and manually trigger them using the command prompt. following link can be useful they have explained it very nicely

- https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-selenium-grid.html
- https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/grid_4/setting_up_your_own_grid/